# Existence of a fixed point for a linear stationary iterative method

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Suppose you are attempting to solve $Ax = b$ using linear stationary iteration method defined by $$x_k = G x_{k-1} + f$$ that is consistent with $Ax = b$, i.e., for which $f = (I - G)A^{-1}b$. Suppose the eigenvalues of $G$ are real and such that $|\lambda_1| > 1$ and $|\lambda_i| < 1$ for $2\leq i \leq n$. Also, suppose that $G$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, $z_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$.
>
> a.) Show that there exists an initial condition $x_0$ such that $x_k\rightarrow x = A^{-1}b$
>
> b.) Does your answer give a characterization of selecting $x_0$ that could be used in practice to create an algorithm that would ensure convergence?

Solution a.) - Let $e^{(k)} = x_k - x$ be the error on step $k$. We know that $$e^{(0)} = \alpha_1 z_1 \sum_{i=2}^{n}\alpha_i z_i, \ \ \|z_i\| = 1$$ $$e^{(k)} = \lambda_1^{k}\alpha_1 z_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n}\lambda_i^{k}\alpha_i z_i$$ If $x_0$ is such that $\alpha_1 = 0$ then $$e^{(0)} = \sum_{i=2}^{n}\alpha_i z_i$$ $$e^{(k)} = \sum_{i=2}^{n}\lambda_i^{k}\alpha_i z_i$$ Since $|\lambda_i| < 1$ for $2\leq i\leq n$ it follows that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow 0} e^{(k)} = 0$$ therefore there is a fixed point $x^* = A^{-1}b$.

Solution b.) This is not a practical characterization since $e^(0)$ and $z_1$ are not known therefore we cannot be sure $\alpha_1 = 0$.

I am not really sure if this is correct. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. This is not homework. I am preparing for a qualifier exam at the end of August in Computational Mathematics.

Comment: I suppose you could find the eigenvectors of $A$, but this seems harder than just finding $A^{-1}$, or using Gaussian elimination to find $A^{-1}b$.  Also, this iteration assumes $f$ is known, but to compute $f$ it seems like you need to first know $A^{-1}b$, in which case you are done and there is no need for the iterations!

Comment: If you know a bound on $|\lambda_1|$ for $G$, you could use $\tilde{G} = \frac{1}{2|\lambda_{max}|}G$, so now $\tilde{G}$ has all eigenvalues less than $1/2$ in magnitude. Of course computing the new $\tilde{f}$ might be difficult, for the same reason that computing $f$ was difficult.

Comment: You could also compute $G^k x_0$ for large $k$, with $G^k x_0 \approx \alpha_1 z_1 \lambda_1^k$.  If you can infer the value of $\lambda_1$ then you can approximate $\alpha_1z_1$ and subtract it out of $x_0$ to form $\tilde{x}_0 = x_0 - \alpha_1z_1$, and now $\tilde{x}_0$ is (approximately) composed only of desirable eigenvectors.

Comment: @Michael good points you made. I find this problem rather difficult and it seems like I am making assumptions to force a fixed point solution, but I don't know another way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One observation, assuming you know $G$.  Let $x_0=v = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i z_i$ for eigenvectors $z_i$ and assume $\alpha_1\neq 0$. Then: 
$$  \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left|\left|\frac{G^k v }{||G^kv||} -sign(\alpha_1 \lambda_1^k) \frac{z_1}{||z_1||}\right|\right| = 0$$
So you can accurately estimate the direction of $z_1$ by considering $\frac{G^k v}{||G^k v||}$ for large $k$.

Similarly, considering $\frac{G^{k+n}v}{||G^k v||}$ for large $k$, I think you can accurately estimate $\lambda_1^n$. So eventually you can indeed "subtract off" an approximation of the component  $\alpha_1 z_1$ from your original vector $v$.

I think this is similar to the technique matlab uses to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a general matrix.